# Chrome 53 How to make the ui smaller?

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu

I've just installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my Dell Inspiron 5574 (originally a Windows machine) and am having trouble getting Chrome's UI to scale back. In the attached image, you can see that the fonts on the bookmarks and in the tab are huge. I've spent probably ~5 hours trying to find a solution.

**How can I scale the Chrome UI back?**
(Similar to how you can scale the Ubuntu UI)

Here are things that didn't:

```
google-chrome --force-device-scale-resolution=1
google-chrome --high-dpi-support=1
```

Here's some useful information:

Dell Inspiron 5574, 1366x768 resolution, Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, Google Chrome 53.0.2785.101

I'm basically just trying to scale back the Chrome UI. I've visited nearly every stackoverflow / google support link relating to this issue. If this question isn't appropriate for this website, please let me know.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my Linux Mint 18 KDE, I used BOTH `--high-dpi-support=1` AND `--force-device-scale-factor=1`, and that fixed the problem.

Use this command:

```
google-chrome --high-dpi-support=1 --force-device-scale-factor=1
```

You can edit the launcher to start Chrome this way when you click on it.

Answer (score 0):

Is that a custom GUI? It's not the 16.04 standard Unity. That is probably the issue.

Comment: I'm using the paper theme. I had this issue before using this theme.

Comment: Can you temporarily switch themes and give it a try?

Comment: I switched back to Adwaita, Ambience, Highcontrast, and Radiance, all of which did not affect the Chrome UI.

Comment: From my research, it appears that Adwaita and other themes are part of GNOME, not Unity. Have you installed a custom desktop environment?

Comment: Besides the paper theme that I installed, I haven't modified anything.